# How to add ArrayList to the GWT ListBox

Tags: java, gwt, arraylist, listbox

I have an arrayList as:

```
final List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

I want to add the outcome `users` of this arrayList to the GWT ListBox.

ListBox is like :

```
 private ListBox test;
 test = new ListBox();
 // Here i want to add the users as additem
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
class CustomListBox extends ListBox {
    public void addUsersList(List<User> userList) {
        for (User user : userList) {
            addItem(user.toString());
    }
}

CustomListBox customListBox = new CustomListBox();
customListBox.addUsersList(getUsersList());
customListBox.setValue(getUsersList().get(1));
```

You also can use [ValueListBox](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueListBox.html) component:

```
ValueListBox<Users> customListBox = new ValueListBox<Users>(new Renderer<Users>() {
    public String render(Users users) {
        String s = "Select a user";
        if(users != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(users.getUsername());
            sb.append("(");
            sb.append(users.getFirstname());
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(users.getLastname());
            sb.append(")").toString();

            s = sb.toString();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void render(Users users, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
        String s = render(users);
        appendable.append(s);
  }
});

customListBox.setValue(getUsersList().get(1));
customListBox.setAcceptableValues(getUsersList());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that you must put a value into ValueListBox first, then assign a list. This is odd. I think it is a bug in Widget because within setAcceptableValues there is update procedure where getting current value (null) is occurred & NPE is risen.